# CSS: hide child element if parent is

Tags: html, css

This is my simplified CSS structure:

```
<div class="quick-shop-form">
  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" etc...>
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    </table>
    <div class="single_variation_wrap">
      <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
        <p class="points">Guadagna fino a <strong>481</strong> Zaeti.</p>
```

How can I hide the paragraph containing `class="points"` when it is under the div containing `class="quick-shop-form"`?

Can I do it via CSS? Or do I need a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through CSS.

This should work:

```
div.quick-shop-form p.points {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! first answer so I first tried it. Easier than expected...I need to practice more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain css:

```css
.quick-shop-form .points {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.quick-shop-form p.points {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-shop-form">
  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" etc...>
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    </table>
    <div class="single_variation_wrap">
      <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
        <p class="points">Guadagna fino a <strong>481</strong> Zaeti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```